# Sum and subtract among column and row cells in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel document where I have some amount in number in different cells. For example, I have number in column H,I,J of row 1.
How can I sum H+I and then subtract J from the result of H+I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Let's say you have your original value in cell H1, the value to add in cell I1, and the value to subtract from their sum in cell J1.

The formula would be:

```
=H1+I1-J1
```

Notes:

1. Since addition and subtraction are related functions, there is no need to add parentheses to enforce proper order of operations.
2. Addition operator and subtraction operator signs work, no need for explicit Excel functions. There is no subtract function in Excel (perhaps where your confusion comes from), so if you wanted to use explicit functions you would write

   =SUM(H1,I1,J1*-1)
3. If you're trying to sum over a larger range (entire columns of I and J, for example), let me know and I'll adapt my response.

[image: solution picture]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add two columns say H1+I1 and subtract J1 from the result(H1+I1) and store the final result into column K1, then first select the K1 column and in the formula section type =H1+I1-J1. In the picture below, I am adding value of A1 and B1. After that subtracting the value of C1 from A1+B1. So, for the cell D1 to show the result of A1+B1-C1, select D1 and write the formula as it is showing in the picture.

[image]